# Converting filter equation to frequency response

Tags: signal-processing

Note: Part of the problem is solved but I've kept the original post for clarity.

[image: filter equation]

I was told this "should be easy" for a filter designer. I am not so sure though, but I'll ask anyway :)

What I need to construct from these equations is a function that takes a frequency range and produces the integrated response of the filter across that range:

```c
float filter_response(float f_low, float f_high) {
  return {magic};
}
```

The frequency response of the filter is known:

[image]

And the expected output from desired function is known from a table for verification:

| c | low | high | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 3.5 | 4.5 | 0.375 |
| 5 | 4.4 | 5.6 | 0.545 |
| 6.3 | 5.6 | 7.0 | 0.727 |
| 8 | 7.1 | 8.9 | 0.873 |
| 10 | 8.8 | 11.2 | 0.951 |
| 12.5 | 11.1 | 13.9 | 0.958 |
| 16 | 14.2 | 17.8 | 0.896 |
| 20 | 17.7 | 22.3 | 0.782 |
| 25 | 22.1 | 27.9 | 0.647 |
| 31.5 | 27.9 | 35.1 | 0.519 |
| 40 | 35.4 | 44.6 | 0.411 |
| 50 | 44.2 | 55.8 | 0.324 |
| 63 | 55.8 | 70.2 | 0.256 |
| 80 | 70.8 | 89.2 | 0.202 |
| 100 | 88.5 | 111.5 | 0.16 |
| 125 | 110.6 | 139.4 | 0.127 |
| 160 | 141.6 | 178.4 | 0.101 |
| 200 | 177.0 | 223.0 | 0.0799 |
| 250 | 221.2 | 278.8 | 0.0634 |
| 315 | 278.8 | 351.2 | 0.0503 |
| 400 | 354.0 | 446.0 | 0.0398 |
| 500 | 442.5 | 557.5 | 0.0315 |
| 630 | 557.5 | 702.5 | 0.0245 |
| 800 | 708.0 | 892.0 | 0.0186 |
| 1000 | 885.0 | 1115.0 | 0.0135 |
| 1250 | 1106.2 | 1393.8 | 0.00894 |
| 1600 | 1416.0 | 1784.0 | 0.00538 |
| 2000 | 1770.0 | 2230.0 | 0.00295 |

Where c is the center frequency, low-high the frequency range, and output the expected output. Only c was originally transcribed from the table: low-high were calculated by me and represent the frequency range of one third octave for the given "mid"-frequency. I provided these for clarity as they directly relate to the desired function.

This is the data that I have and while I am sure this can be done I also understand that this might be beyond what could be expected to get help with online (unless it really is as easy as it was presented to me).

Regardless, any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thank you <3

Since I am neither a filter designer or very well versed in math, I've mainly looked at extracting data from the graph or by interpolating the given values in the table. While this works for now it does not give me the accuracy or trustworthiness I am looking for. I read code in pretty much any language and I understand FIR and IIR filters fairly well.

I've tried designing a filter with Python, SciPy, Numpy based on the given filter constants to see if I could replicate the given response curve, but I've been unsuccessful.

I've also tried AI resources to help me cut through these formulas to give me something that describes the filter in terms that fit my limited knowledge in the field, but they appear wholly unable to deal with this problem.

In the end, I expect to be able to solve this in several different ways. While a function numerically calculating this would be fantastic I could, in theory, also analyze an FFT/FIR filter to produce a new table with the range and precision needed.

Update:

```py
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# constants
pi, f_1, f_2, Q_1, f_3, f_4, Q_2, K = math.pi, 6.31, 1258.9, 0.71, 15.915, 15.915, 0.64, 1    

# band-limiting transfer function
def band_limit(s):
    return ((s**2)*4*(pi**2)*(f_2**2))/(((s**2)+2*pi*f_1*s/Q_1+4*(pi**2)*(f_1**2))*((s**2)+2*pi*f_2*s/Q_1+4*(pi**2)*(f_2**2)))

# frequency-weighting transfer function
def frequency_weight(s):
    return ((s+2*pi*f_3)*2*pi*K*(f_4**2))/(((s**2)+2*pi*f_4*s/Q_2+4*(pi**2)*(f_4**2))*f_3)

px, py, py1, py2 = [], [], [], []

for x in np.arange(1,1000,0.1):
    w = x*2*pi # angular frequency
    px.append(x)
    py1.append(band_limit(w))
    py2.append(frequency_weight(w))
    py.append(band_limit(w)*frequency_weight(w))

plt.plot(px, py1, label = "band-limit filter")
plt.plot(px, py2, label = "frequency-weighting filter")
plt.plot(px, py, label = "total")
plt.yscale("log");
plt.xscale("log");
plt.ylim(0.01, 1);
plt.xlim(1, 1000);
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This python program produces the following plot:

[image]

I've overlaid the original plot for comparison.

The plots do not match, but they appear not entirely dissimilar which tells me I am on the right path. Is it possible to use a real-only valued function to calculate the amplitude response at each frequency or is the error I am getting due to not performing the calculations with complex numbers?

Update:

Apparently the calculation must be done with complex math as the following python code and diagram shows (a near perfect match):

```py
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cmath

# constants
pi, f_1, f_2, Q_1, f_3, f_4, Q_2, K = math.pi, 6.31, 1258.9, 0.71, 15.915, 15.915, 0.64, 1    

# band-limiting transfer function
def band_limit(s):
    z = ((s**2)*4*(pi**2)*(f_2**2))/(((s**2)+2*pi*f_1*s/Q_1+4*(pi**2)*(f_1**2))*((s**2)+2*pi*f_2*s/Q_1+4*(pi**2)*(f_2**2)))
    return math.sqrt(z.real**2+z.imag**2)

# frequency-weighting transfer function
def frequency_weight(s):
    z = ((s+2*pi*f_3)*2*pi*K*(f_4**2))/(((s**2)+2*pi*f_4*s/Q_2+4*(pi**2)*(f_4**2))*f_3)
    return math.sqrt(z.real**2+z.imag**2)

px, py, py1, py2 = [], [], [], []


for x in np.arange(1,1259.9,0.1):
    w = x*2*pi # angular frequency
    px.append(x)
    py1.append(band_limit(complex(1.0,w)))
    py2.append(frequency_weight(complex(1.0,w)))
    py.append(band_limit(complex(1.0,w))*frequency_weight(complex(1.0,w)))

plt.plot(px, py1, label = "band-limit filter")
plt.plot(px, py2, label = "frequency-weighting filter")
plt.plot(px, py, label = "total")
plt.yscale("log");
plt.xscale("log");
plt.ylim(0.01, 1);
plt.xlim(1, 1259.9);
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: matching plot]

The only question left is how do I integrate this across a range to produce the function originally asked for, such that it could produce the verification table?

Comment: All you really need to do is mechanically type in the formulas calling the subscripted variables f1, f2, q1, f3, f4, q2 etc. in the language of your choice and you should be their. Beware that electronic engineers choose sqrt(-1) = j = -i (the maths choice). Other than that you should be able to just type in the formulas and have them work. Or you could model it in a spreadsheet if that is more comfortable for you.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your response! I've done that, but I don't understand the results - most likely because I do not understand "s = j2π", thus what the formula is giving me. I've read that the frequency response of a transfer function is given by simply replacing s = jω, which also is beyond me. I am not exactly familiar with complex-numbered math or the integration that I need to do on the frequency response equivalent of the transfer function. While less elegant I could certainly do away with the integration though.

Comment: You do need complex numbers to get the final result. Terms linear in s are imaginary (out of phase by 90 degrees with the input signal) whilst constant and terms in s^2 are in phase. You are interested in the amplitude response of the filter ignoring the phase. Look for some radio ham filter code which can probably do what you want in a pre canned way without you needing to understand complex numbers. It isn't that hard to find the magnitude of a complex number | x + iy | = sqrt((x+iy)*(x-iy)) = sqrt(x^2+y^2) but obviously it is easier in a language which has native complex numbers.

Comment: I understand complex numbers to some degree, certainly enough to get their magnitude and phase, as I would after an FFT. Still does not help me much with the formula as a whole. How about something simpler: H(s) = 2π²Fs/Q where F and Q are variables? I could work from that. I would do func(s) return (2*pow(pi,2)*F*s)/Q which is real-numbered (in target language), and I assume useless. I could learn to convert that work with complex numbers - but I would still not know what the input s or output represents. phase+magnitude as complex "vector" in, same out does not make sense to me.

Comment: This is neither here nor there, but the horizontal axis on the frequency response plot is deeply cursed. If and when you reproduce the plot, stick to exact powers of 2.

Comment: What are fc, flow, fhigh? How do they map to f1, f2, f3?

Comment: Ok, so I understand that the input complex number should be s=σ+jω where ω is angular frequency (i assume σ is magnitude?). I am still not doing any complex math, but even with a real-valued-only function, using angular frequency for s and plotting the output I am actually getting something that looks similar to the provided graph... I wonder, not being interested in phase response, is it possible that simply running the formula as if it were real-only and using s=ω that I will get a the frequency response? It doesn't match the plot exactly, which has me worried.

Comment: "c", "low" and "high" do not map to f1, f2, f3. They are the center, low and high frequency of a range, over which the integrated amplitude response of the filter (described by the equation using f1, f2, f3, etc.) should be "output". If you look in the plot around, for example, 6.3Hz(c) you can gauge that the response could very well be 0.727(output) if integrated across 5.6(low) to 7.0(high) Hz.

Comment: I see. Well, I have results. They're sort of close, but there will be some interpretation necessary. This is only valid in the complex domain, not the real domain.

Comment: Chat in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256688/discussion-between-ronald-mcfuglethorn-and-reinderien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems fine, though I don't know what your tolerances are:

```py
from io import StringIO

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.integrate
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def Hb(
    s: float | np.ndarray,
    f1: float = 6.310,
    f2: float = 1258.9,
    Q1: float = 0.71,
) -> np.ndarray:
    from numpy import pi
    w1 = 2*pi*f1
    w2 = 2*pi*f2

    return (s * w2)**2 / (
        s**2 + w1*s/Q1 + w1**2
    ) / (
        s**2 + w2*s/Q1 + w2**2
    )


def Hw(
    s: float | np.ndarray,
    f3: float = 15.915,
    f4: float = 15.915,
    Q2: float = 0.64,
    K: int = 1,
) -> np.ndarray:
    from numpy import pi
    w3 = 2*pi*f3
    w4 = 2*pi*f4

    return (s + w3) * (
        K * w4**2
    ) / (
        s**2 + w4*s/Q2 + w4**2
    ) / w3


def H(f: float | np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    s = 2j * np.pi * f
    return Hb(s) * Hw(s)


def load_reference() -> pd.DataFrame:
    content = '''
fc  flow    fhigh   output
4   3.5     4.5     0.375
5   4.4     5.6     0.545
6.3     5.6     7.0     0.727
8   7.1     8.9     0.873
10  8.8     11.2    0.951
12.5    11.1    13.9    0.958
16  14.2    17.8    0.896
20  17.7    22.3    0.782
25  22.1    27.9    0.647
31.5    27.9    35.1    0.519
40  35.4    44.6    0.411
50  44.2    55.8    0.324
63  55.8    70.2    0.256
80  70.8    89.2    0.202
100     88.5    111.5   0.16
125     110.6   139.4   0.127
160     141.6   178.4   0.101
200     177.0   223.0   0.0799
250     221.2   278.8   0.0634
315     278.8   351.2   0.0503
400     354.0   446.0   0.0398
500     442.5   557.5   0.0315
630     557.5   702.5   0.0245
800     708.0   892.0   0.0186
1000    885.0   1115.0  0.0135
1250    1106.2  1393.8  0.00894
1600    1416.0  1784.0  0.00538
2000    1770.0  2230.0  0.00295
    '''
    with StringIO(content) as f:
        return pd.read_csv(f, delim_whitespace=True)


def get_actual(ref: pd.DataFrame) -> np.ndarray:
    return np.abs(H(ref['fc']))


def get_interval_mean(ref: pd.DataFrame) -> np.ndarray:
    # This is needed because scipy can't vectorise bounds
    integ = np.array([
        scipy.integrate.quad(
            func=H, a=row['flow'], b=row['fhigh'], complex_func=True,
        )[0]
        for idx, row in ref.iterrows()
    ])
    means = integ/(ref['fhigh'] - ref['flow'])
    return means.abs()


def verify_band_limiting(ref: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
    assert np.allclose(
        a=ref['actual'],
        b=ref['output'],
        rtol=0.05, atol=0,
    )


def plot(ref: pd.DataFrame) -> plt.Figure:
    fig, (ax_transfer, ax_err) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

    f_actual = np.exp(np.linspace(np.log(1), np.log(2000), 250))
    ax_transfer.loglog(f_actual, np.abs(H(f_actual)), label='actual', color='orange')

    ax_transfer.scatter(
        ref['fc'], ref['output'],
        label='reference', color='black', s=1, zorder=10,
    )

    ax_transfer.set_xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
    ax_transfer.set_ylabel('Magnitude')

    legend_kwargs = {'label': 'interval mean'}
    for idx, row in ref.iterrows():
        ax_transfer.plot(
            [row['flow'], row['fc'], row['fhigh']],
            [row['interval_mean'], row['actual'], row['interval_mean']],
            color='lightgreen', **legend_kwargs,
        )
        legend_kwargs = {}
    ax_transfer.legend()

    ax_err.semilogx(
        ref['fc'], np.zeros_like(ref['actual']),
        label='actual', color='orange')
    ax_err.scatter(
        ref['fc'], ref['output']/ref['actual'] - 1,
        label='reference', color='black', marker='+')
    ax_err.scatter(
        ref['fc'], ref['interval_mean']/ref['actual'] - 1,
        label='interval_mean', color='green', marker='+')
    ax_err.set_xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
    ax_err.set_ylabel('Relative magnitude error')
    ax_err.legend()

    return fig


def main() -> None:
    ref = load_reference()
    ref['actual'] = get_actual(ref)
    ref['interval_mean'] = get_interval_mean(ref)

    verify_band_limiting(ref)
    print(ref)

    plot(ref=ref)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
        fc    flow   fhigh   output    actual  interval_mean
0      4.0     3.5     4.5  0.37500  0.379550       0.378397
1      5.0     4.4     5.6  0.54500  0.545093       0.540838
2      6.3     5.6     7.0  0.72700  0.728996       0.721519
3      8.0     7.1     8.9  0.87300  0.879784       0.870259
4     10.0     8.8    11.2  0.95100  0.954051       0.943934
5     12.5    11.1    13.9  0.95800  0.960305       0.952859
6     16.0    14.2    17.8  0.89600  0.893056       0.887968
7     20.0    17.7    22.3  0.78200  0.781253       0.779000
8     25.0    22.1    27.9  0.64700  0.650180       0.650352
9     31.5    27.9    35.1  0.51900  0.521334       0.522628
10    40.0    35.4    44.6  0.41100  0.409186       0.410701
11    50.0    44.2    55.8  0.32400  0.325219       0.326599
12    63.0    55.8    70.2  0.25600  0.256466       0.257566
13    80.0    70.8    89.2  0.20200  0.200944       0.201825
14   100.0    88.5   111.5  0.16000  0.160218       0.160919
15   125.0   110.6   139.4  0.12700  0.127881       0.128439
16   160.0   141.6   178.4  0.10100  0.099738       0.100168
17   200.0   177.0   223.0  0.07990  0.079705       0.080044
18   250.0   221.2   278.8  0.06340  0.063703       0.063969
19   315.0   278.8   351.2  0.05030  0.050487       0.050690
20   400.0   354.0   446.0  0.03980  0.039636       0.039786
21   500.0   442.5   557.5  0.03150  0.031490       0.031595
22   630.0   557.5   702.5  0.02450  0.024557       0.024621
23   800.0   708.0   892.0  0.01860  0.018501       0.018531
24  1000.0   885.0  1115.0  0.01350  0.013510       0.013529
25  1250.0  1106.2  1393.8  0.00894  0.009104       0.009141
26  1600.0  1416.0  1784.0  0.00538  0.005255       0.005314
27  2000.0  1770.0  2230.0  0.00295  0.002939       0.002992
```

[image: error plots]